# invoke modal operator from python and block until completion

Tags: python, scripting

Seemingly I have a rather non-standard use case here.
In fact, I could solve my actual use case by a different approach.

Yet still, I'd like to find out about the following question:

Is it possible to invoke a *modal operator* from a python script and **block** until its completion? Do I need to call the operator with some specific magic incantation? Or is there at least a known workaround?

---

Somehow I get the feel that I am missing out on something very basic; I am fully aware that a modal operator typically involves user interaction. And I see that several people tried to launch and remote control modal operators from a script. However that is not what I want. I simply want to invoke the operator synchronously and block on it.

Comment: What do you want it to block?

Comment: script execution of course. Like when invoking a non modal operator. Or like with a synchronous procedure call.

Comment: Then why not make it non-modal? What is it that you're doing that requires this type of functionality? I think it might be good to add some more context as to what you're doing to help people understand the context for this.

Comment: because I didn't write it, I want to call it.